# AngularJS log JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, logging

Is there a way to output JSON response that is coming from the server? I am trying the following, with undesirable output:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'getUser' })
        .success(function (data,status) {
            $scope.user = data;
            console.log("User="+data);})
        .error(function (data,status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            if(status==403)
                $location.path( "/" );
        });
```

Output:

```
User=[object Object]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can `stringify` it before printing.

```
console.log("User = " + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `angular.toJson()` if you don't want to add a new dependency:

```
$log.debug(angular.toJson(data, true));
```

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

Comment: The best answer by FAR!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your browser, the `log` function can take multiple parameters.  Chrome, for instance, supports this:

```
console.log("User = ", data);
```

When you do this, `data` shows up in an object browser which you can show/collapse the hierarchy.  It is extremely useful.  Since I develop in Chrome, I vastly prefer this method (over `JSON.stringify`) because it is less typing and the debugging experience is better.

If you are stuck debugging in a browser that doesn't support this syntax, then `JSON.stringify` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Although JSON.stringify(val) wouldn't throw any error for any datatypes, this is much easier than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`console.dir(object)` is what you are looking for. It is now widely supported in all browsers (IE9+). The output can be viewed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir).